# Weird behavior when copying one hash to another

Tags: ruby

I have a class which manages configuration (saved locally as JSON) and I've written a method to copy configuration from one file to another. Both JSON files are loaded as hashes into instance variables (`@local` and `@repository`, respectively). I've run into some strange behavior where setting a key on one hash is overwriting the value for the same key in the other hash. I've narrowed my issue down to line 14 of the code snippet below. My `puts` statement on line 12 shows `@repository[brand][:branches][branch]` as being a non-empty hash with data, while my `puts` statement on line 21 shows `@repository[brand][:branches][branch]` as being an empty hash.

```
def copy(brand, branch = nil)
    brand = brand.to_sym
    branch =  branch.to_sym

    if branch.nil?
        if @local[:repository].has_key?(brand)
            @local[:repository][brand].deep_merge(@repository[brand])
        else
            @local[:repository][brand] = @repository[brand]
        end
    else
        puts @repository[brand][:branches][branch]
        unless @local[:repository].has_key?(brand)
            @local[:repository][brand] = @repository[brand]
            @local[:repository][brand][:branches] = Hash.new
        end

        unless @local[:repository][brand][:branches].has_key?(branch)
            @local[:repository][brand][:branches][branch] = Hash.new
        end
        puts @repository[brand][:branches][branch]
        @local[:repository][brand][:branches][branch].deep_merge(@repository[brand][:branches][branch])
    end

    self.write(CONFIG_FILE, @local)
end
```

If I change line 14 to `@local[:repository][brand] = Hash.new`, the value for that hash on line 21 is no longer empty and is in fact the expected value. One key thing is that the `brand` key in `@local[:repository]` doesn't exist yet.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: This is not related to your actual question, but you should read up on how to use the `unless` in RoR. http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/ And clean up that `if` statement, I have no chance of understanding what's going on.

Comment: I actually have read that page re: unless, and as far as I can tell, I'm using it how they recommended. I'm not checking for anything being nil nor do I have multiple conditions in either of my unless statements. Also, I'm not checking for else conditions in either case, either. So, unless seems cleaner to me.

As for the `if` statement being cleaned up, care to elaborate on that?

Comment: Where is the problem in this code? You just posted a wall of code, but nowhere does it explain the expected outcome nor the location of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't know where the problem is, but the problem itself is clearly explained in my post. Setting the value of one key in one hash is also setting the value for that same key in the other hash, but this *only happens when I use symbols as keys*.

Comment: No, it's not clear which hashes you're talking about, and which value is overwritten. Note that the first example is done on `@local`, the second one is done on `local`, which is basically a dup of `@local` via json.

Comment: Setting a key in `@local` is overwriting values in `@repository`, but only when using symbols as keys. This doesn't happen when using `irb`, but it does happen when I execute my code, and I have no idea what could possibly be going on.

Comment: Yet you don't show any concrete example of what has been modified, when and where. Please come back with a clearer example.

Comment: I'm re-wording the question because I finally discovered the actual offending line in the code.

Comment: There is still way too much code, and worse, way too convoluted code here for a [mcve]. Please, try to trim the code down to the minimum amount of code that still exhibits your problem. It is almost impossible to follow the convoluted nest of conditionals to figure out what may or may not be wrong. One thing I noted though: in the title you talk about copying, but I don't see any place where you actually copy anything.

Comment: The question is perfectly sane. The guy just didn't fully understand what he was doing. But hey, this is exactly where stackoverflow can jump in and help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit lies in this line (which you use twice):

```
@local[:repository][brand] = @repository[brand]
```

This does not make a copy of the hash that resides in `@repository[brand]`. 
Let's split that up a bit so we can talk about it more clearly:

```
brand_detail = @repository[brand]
local_repo = @local[:repository]
local_repo[brand] = brand_detail
```

After the third statement, `local_repo[brand]` will not contain a *copy* of the `brand_details` hash but instead a *reference* to that hash. So now all of these lines would have the same effect; they would all modify the same hash instance:

- `brand_detail[:branches] = 3`
- `local_repo[brand][:branches] = 3`
- `@repository[brand][:branches] = 3`

You should be able to circumvent this by explicitly adding a copy instead of a reference using `dup`:

```
@local[:repository][brand] = @repository[brand].dup
```